# htaccess mime type

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, mime, file-extension

The goal is to create a customized file extension for my *.php test script using .htaccess, I would like to customize a file extension so that when Apache2 "sees" it, then Apache will execute it like a PHP script. Blow is an example

the test URL is:

```
localhost/index.xyz
```

the .htaccess is at directory www and is one line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5    xyz
```

the php file, "test.xyz" to run is:

```
<?php
echo "hello, I am a xyz file...";
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't it better to use `mod_rewrite` instead? This would allow only have `.xyz` urls, but `.php` in filesystem

Comment: have you tried `AddType x-httpd-php5 xyz` or `<FilesMatch "\.(xyz)$"> SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5 </FilesMatch>` ? some times the 'application/' in the AddType causes issues...  but the filesmatch also works well..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .xyz
```